# How execute In Application Programming code

Tags: stm32, stm32f3

I write program with labview to read bin file of compiled  STM32F103 code and send it to st micro with serial port
Also in st micro i write program to get bin file from serial port
My st micro code start address is 0x8000000 with 0x4000 size
And my application code start address is 0x8004000 with 0x8000 size

I sucessfully write my received bin code in 0x8004000 but i don't know how to execute my code
I try to use stm cube iap example method :

```
JumpAddress =*(__IO uint32_t*) (APPLICATION_ADDRESS +4);
JumpToApplication=(pFunction) JumpAddress;
__set_MSP(*(__IO uint32_t*)     APPLICATION_ADDRESS) ;
JumpToApplication() ;
```

but it don't work

I try to use stm cube iap example method :

```
JumpAddress =*(__IO uint32_t*) (APPLICATION_ADDRESS +4);
JumpToApplication=(pFunction) JumpAddress;
__set_MSP(*(__IO uint32_t*) APPLICATION_ADDRESS) ;
JumpToApplication() ;
```

but it don't work

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far. It is really difficult to give an answer to a problem where we don't ahve the full picture. Show what code you have written. How do you receive the bin data? where to you write it? are you sure it is written in the correct place? have you debugged it?